# What happens in the main thread when using dup2 in a child thread?

Tags: c++, fork, dup2

This is a short version of my code:

```
FILE *fd = tmpfile();
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0){
  dup2(fileno(fd), 1);
  std::cout<<"FIRST WRITE"<<std::endl;
}else{ // we are in main thread
  waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
  std::cout<<"SECOND WRITE"<<std::endl;
}
```

My questions are:

1. "FIRST WRITE" is written to `fd`, right?
2. Where is "SECOND WRITE" written to? I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two processes, not two threads.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: when I try it, "SECOND WRITE" is written in shell and is not redirected to fd, but I wanted to make sure that this is what suppose to happen...

Comment: You have created a second process which is independent of the first and has its own i/o descriptors.

Comment: great thanks  Mark Setchell